# How can I handle Std-Lib dependencies with Bundler + Gems?

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I put all my gems in a Gemfile I can just use

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require :default
```

to load all gems. Now I want to use modules from Ruby's Std-Lib. Of course I can do

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'json'
[etc.]
```

But most of those modules are already loaded by the required gems. So I don't get errors if I don't require them. But if I would remove a gem, this could easily change.

Is there a nice way to handle those dependencies (besides testing)?

Comment: Require them explicitly. Don't depend on your gem to do i for you.

Comment: Okay, but how do I know which ones to require? Do I have to look up all modules? Example: `File` is in Core and cannot be required, but `FileUtils` is in StdLib and has to be required.

Comment: It's not hard. Just look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there is no better way than finding out all needed modules manually and require'ing them manually.

I used this hack to find a list of modules that need to be required:

```
find -name *.rb |xargs cat |egrep -o ' [A-Z][a-zA-Z]*(\.|::)' |tr -dc A-Za-z\\n |sort |uniq |xargs -I@ -n1 egrep -o '(module|class) @' -r /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/* |cut -d':' -f2 |sort |uniq
```

It's not perfect but should cover most cases.